# Google Maps API - Polylines snap to road limit

Tags: javascript, google-maps, polyline

I am building several polylines snap to road. Below the code for 2 of them. Above 15 polylines snap to road, I have the following error: "Directions request failed: OVER_QUERY_LIMIT".

Thus, I'd like to find a solution. One of them would consist in putting all those informations in cache in my computer, so the only thing I get from Google Maps is the map. Is that possible ?

Do you know some other solutions ?

```
//Circuit CHL1C1

CHL1C1 = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(-22.91401,-68.192237),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-23.226361,-67.064938)
    ];

var traceCHL1C1 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: CHL1C1,
    strokeColor: "red",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 4
});

var serviceCHL1C1 = new google.maps.DirectionsService(),traceCHL1C1,snap_pathCHL1C1=[];
traceCHL1C1.setMap(map);
for(j=0;j<CHL1C1.length-1;j++){
    serviceCHL1C1.route({origin: CHL1C1[j],destination: CHL1C1[j+1],travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING},function(result, status) {
        if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            snap_pathCHL1C1 = snap_pathCHL1C1.concat(result.routes[0].overview_path);
            traceCHL1C1.setPath(snap_pathCHL1C1);
        } else alert("Directions request failed: "+status);        
    });
}




//Circuit CHL1C2

CHL1C2 = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(-22.898988,-68.198154),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-22.337195,-68.016747),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-22.443062,-68.899408)
];

var traceCHL1C2 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: CHL1C2,
    strokeColor: "green",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 4
});

var serviceCHL1C2 = new google.maps.DirectionsService(),traceCHL1C2,snap_pathCHL1C2=[];
traceCHL1C2.setMap(map);
for(j=0;j<CHL1C2.length-1;j++){
    serviceCHL1C2.route({origin: CHL1C2[j],destination: CHL1C2[j+1],travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING},function(result, status) {
        if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            snap_pathCHL1C2 = snap_pathCHL1C2.concat(result.routes[0].overview_path);
            traceCHL1C2.setPath(snap_pathCHL1C2);
        } else alert("Directions request failed: "+status);        
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but there is a maximum of 8 waypoints with the free API.

Answer (score 0):

There are a maximum of 8 waypoints with the free API.  However depending on what you're trying to do, you can get around this limitation by creating an array of polylines and calling the directions service exactly once for each element in the array.